# Properly discarding ctypes pointers to mmap memory in Python

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes, mmap, memoryview

I have the issue that I cannot properly close mmap-s in Python after I created a pointer to them. My use case is that I open files (usually that is UIO-devices to work with hardware, but the issue also happens with normal files), memory-map them and then use them as buffers for ctypes-structures. Usually structs or arrays of data. A minimal example looks like this:

```
import ctypes as ct
import mmap
import os

fileno = os.open('/tmp/testfile', os.O_RDWR | os.O_SYNC)
map = mmap.mmap(fileno, 32768, flags=mmap.MAP_SHARED)
memory = (ct.c_uint32 * 8192).from_buffer(map)

# Use the memory object to do things here

del memory
map.close()
os.close(fileno)
```

Everything is fine at that point.

However, sometimes I need to call some C library functions that also need access to that memory so I have to pass in a pointer to them. I create that pointer using:

```
ptr = ct.cast(memory, ct.c_void_p)
```

All of that works very well except one thing. As soon as I create such a pointer, I can no longer close the memory map. Take this slightly extended example:

```
import ctypes as ct
import mmap
import os

fileno = os.open('/tmp/testfile', os.O_RDWR | os.O_SYNC)
map = mmap.mmap(fileno, 32768, flags=mmap.MAP_SHARED)
memory = (ct.c_uint32 * 8192).from_buffer(map)

# Use the memory object to do things here
ptr = ct.cast(memory, ct.c_void_p)
del ptr

del memory
map.close()
os.close(fileno)
```

Running this results in the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pointer_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    map.close()
BufferError: cannot close exported pointers exist

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've run some analysis (using gc.get_referrers) on what is referencing the `map`-instance and it turns out that there is a `memoryview`-instance still there. In the end, this traces back to the ctypes Array:

```
[<__main__.c_uint_Array_8192 object at 0x7f954bd1e0>,
 [{547965620704: <__main__.c_uint_Array_8192 object at 0x7f954bd1e0>,
   'ffffffff': <memory at 0x7f95621a08>},
  [<memory at 0x7f95621a08>,
   [<managedbuffer object at 0x7f95746d08>,
```

However, this does not really help me. I'd like to know how I can get rid of that pointer. I know that this is likely not fully safe since I could, of course, always have a copy of that pointer somewhere. But completely preventing closing the `mmap` after a pointer was created also does not seem like a good idea. Anyone knows how I can convince Python that I discarded all the pointers and it is now safe to close the mmap?

Comment: Did the same test as you and got the same result. I thought it was just a ref being kept by python somewhere, so I just did: `import gc` and `gc.collect()` and tried to close the mem mapped file immediately after that: it worked... I can't see any other way to tell python that there are no refs on the mem map :(

Comment: I'm stuck with this problem, too. In a larger code env where classes and finalizers are involved, it feels near-impossible to correctly track down all views of the mmap. Why can't we just get an "unsafe" mode that allows freeing the mmap even while views are still in existence?

Comment: After wasting a lot of time, I finally found the causes. One was that a reference to a view ended up as last value of a for loop variable which had to be del'ed explicitly. The other was a reference on class level. We close the mmap in a weakref finalizer of said class. Since the object being finalized is not accessible, I presumed that the reference was gone, but apparently the object still exists while the finalizer is running. That creates a rather serious design problem, since we cannot get rid of the reference in the finalizer.
Cf https://github.com/pypdfium2-team/pypdfium2/pull/237

Comment: Possible workaround is to store the attribute in question in a list (or other mutable object) and pass it through the finalizer, where we can clear the reference. To keep access convenient on class level, I guess it should be possible to create a wrapper property returning index 0 of the list attribute.

Answer (score 1):

find the memoryview instance and call `memoryview-instance.release()` first, then you can close the mmap instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `addressof` to launder the reference; i.e. `ptr = ct.cast(ct.addressof(memory), ct.c_void_p)`